# Do not run some job until some other job is running

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have two different jobs.
These jobs could be started independently of each other.
But they work with the same object.
And I would like to have only one of these jobs running at the same time.

Is it possible to configure job in Hudson/Jenkins to do not run until some other jobs are running?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [locks and latches plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin). If I understood your question correctly, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: This plugin is deprecated. But there is Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Build triggers**  - Build after other projects are built.

Use this trigger option to achieve your task.

Answer (score 0):

point the job to run on a specific environment which limit the job to run simultaneously. with this the second job will be in the queue rather than running together